# How to log out off yu-gi-oh duel links account / gmail

Tags: yu-gi-oh-duel-links

I started this game yesterday, now my brother wants to play this game on his own account but on the same device (tablet). We tried already just another login on another gmail account, but he is still on my account and can use my cards and see the progress. So how we can play this game on our own accounts?

Comment: You can self-answer your question so that others can find the answer.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot log out of an account because your data is stored on the konami servers and that is linked to your device so no matter what you do. you cannot log out.